# C++ function strprint(expr, expr, expr...) almost works, but not quite, why?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, variadic-templates

Here's a small C++ 'strprint' function that seems to *mostly* work:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// send_to_stream: send all arguments to the specified stream.
inline void send_to_stream(std::ostream &os) {}
template <typename ARG, typename... REST>
inline void send_to_stream(std::ostream &os, const ARG &arg, const REST & ... rest) {
    os << arg;
    send_to_stream(os, rest...);
}

// strprint: convert all arguments to a string by sending them to a stringstream.
template <typename... ARGS>
std::string strprint(const ARGS & ... args) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    send_to_stream(oss, args...);
    return oss.str();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string s1 = strprint("five:", 5, "\n");
    std::cout << "S1=" << s1 << "." << std::endl;

    // std::string s2 = strprint("five:", 5, std::endl);
    // std::cout << "S2=" << s1 << "." << std::endl;
};
```

This program, when run, produces the output:

```
five:5
.
```

which is exactly what I would expect.  But when I uncomment the 's2' lines, I get a compile error:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
foo.cpp:25:53: error: too many arguments to function ‘std::string strprint(const ARGS& ...) [with ARGS = {}; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
   25 |      std::string s2 = strprint("five:", 5, std::endl);
      |                                                     ^
foo.cpp:15:13: note: declared here
   15 | std::string strprint(const ARGS & ... args) {
      |             ^~~~~~~~
```

This makes no sense.  Too many arguments to a function that takes an unlimited number of arguments?  It doesn't seem to like passing 'std::endl' through a variadic list.
Why not?  What am I missing?

Comment: What data type is `std::endl`?  What would make it something that is passable as an argument?

Comment: `std::endl`, being a function template, has no type. So `ARGS...` can't be properly deduced, and ends up being deduced as an empty list.

Comment: fwiw the number of arguments is not unlimited. The limit is just high enough that usually you don't enounter it.

Comment: @jyelon On a side note, your variadic templates should be using [*forwarding references*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) rather than const lvalue references, eg: `template <typename ARG, typename... REST> inline void send_to_stream(std::ostream &os, ARG &&arg, REST &&... rest) { os << std::forward<ARG>(arg); send_to_stream(os, std::forward<REST>(rest)...); }` `template <typename... ARGS> std::string strprint(ARGS && ... args) { ... send_to_stream(oss, std::forward<ARGS>(args)...); ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::endl` is a [function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl):

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

Admittedly, the error message is rather confusing. The problem is that the type of `std::endl` cannot be deduced, because you would need to instantitate the function first:

```
std::string s2 = strprint("five:", 5, std::endl<std::ostream::char_type,std::ostream::traits_type>);
std::cout << "S2=" << s1 << "." << std::endl;
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eYPo48GdW)

The usual

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

works due to overload 20 here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt. Generally all io manipulators are functions that take the stream as parameter. And generall all io manipulators that are only defined for input or output streams, respectively, are function templates.

Of course you do not want to explicitly provide the `char_type` and `traits_type`. As pointed out by Remy Lebeau, you can use a (non-capturing) lambda:

```
auto endl = [](std::ostream os&){ os << std::endl; }; 
std::string s2 = strprint("five:", 5, endl);
```

This will call overload 18 (from avove link).

Comment: Thanks!  That makes sense.  So how does operator << accept a function template as a parameter on the right-hand side?  Is there any way I could do the same magic myself?

Comment: @jyelon https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt 18

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number actually, `std::endl` would use overload #20 not #18, as it takes/returns a `basic_ostream&` not a `ios_base&` or `basic_ios&`

Comment: @jyelon `ostream::operator<<` has an overload that accepts a C-style function pointer matching `std::endl`'s signature. The compiler can deduce the type of `std::endl` to instantiate because the operator's parameter uses the template arguments of the `ostream` being printed to. That is not the case with your `strprint()`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number a less verbose solution would be to use a lambda instead of an explicit instantiation, eg: `auto endl = [](std::ostream os&){ os << std::endl; }; std::string s2 = strprint("five:", 5, endl);` [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/678sf5Pbh)

Comment: Or just stick to `"\n"`, `std::endl` is rarely needed

Comment: @AlanBirtles its not just `endl` but also most other io manipulators